# Google Cloud Objectify - Error saving entity

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify, datastore

I want to save an entity and seems to be falling because I am trying to index a HashMap which has a list.

Here are my classes:

**IndicadorEntity **

```
@Entity
public final class IndicadorEntity {
    private @Index Map<String, List<ObjetivoEntity>> objetivos;
}
```

**ObjetivoEntity**

package com.eulen.google.efqm.datastore.entities;

import java.util.Date;

```
public final class ObjetivoEntity {
    private double objetivo;
    private boolean variable;
    private Date fechaCreacion;
}
```

When trying to save **IndicadorEntity** I get the following error:

```
com.googlecode.objectify.SaveException: Error saving com.eulen.google.efqm.datastore.entities.IndicadorEntity@694e7f0b: objetivos.2: java.util.ArrayList is not a supported property type.
```

If I remove @Index it works, but I need to know which **IndicadorEntity** has null objetivos.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are limits to what the datastore will index. However, you can almost always work around this by creating a synthetic index.

For example, you can make a field `private List<String> myCustomIndex` and populate it with an `onSave` method, filling it with all the things you want to be able to search for. You can extract information from objects at any depth in your object hierarchy.

Then query on your custom index: `filter("myCustomIndex", somevalue)`

Comment: thought it'd be possible as I saw a question with a solution about how to query a hashmap with objectify, here iin SO

Comment: That message "...is not a supported property type" comes from Google's low level API. Out of curiosity, is this v5 or v6? The underlying low level API for v6 (the cloud sdk) is a little more capable than the old appengine API with respect to indexing, but I don't know if it will help you here.

Comment: i am using version 5